# how can I make this dynamic line in css which shows rating in popup accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: set rating]

I wanna make this line which if you stretch, it changes value and display that value in that small popup.
thanks

Comment: Try to provide [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking question

Comment: solution in vanilla js or in React,js would be really helpful 

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :
Not exactly but almost same.

```js
var step = 10;

$(".slider").each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var slider = self.slider({
        create: function() {
            self.find('#tooltip').text(self.slider('value'));
        },
        slide: function(event, ui) {
           self.find('#tooltip').text(self.slider('value'));
            self.on('mouseup touchend', setPathData);
            self.on('mousedown touchstart', setPathData1);       
        },
        range: 'min',
        min: 1,
        max: step,
        value: 1,
        step: 0.1
    });
});

function setPathData() {
  $(this).find('.puls').addClass('active')
  $(this).find('.puls').addClass(' color')
}
function setPathData1() {
  $(this).find('.puls').removeClass('active')
  $(this).find('.puls').removeClass('color')
}
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 320px;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .slider .ui-slider-range {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #f9b315;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .slider .ui-slider-handle {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    outline: none;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
  }
  .slider .ui-slider-handle svg {
    fill: #FFF;
  }
  .slider .ui-slider-handle:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(202, 239, 255, 0.6);
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateZ(-1px);
  }
  .slider .ui-slider-handle.active:after {
    animation: anim-effect-sanja 1.1s ease-out forwards;
  }
  .slider .ui-slider-handle.color svg {
    fill: #f9b315;
  }
  .slider .ui-slider-handle.ui-state-active {
    cursor: grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
  }
  .slider .text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 16px;
    transform: translate(0, -80px);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
  .slider .text strong {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  @keyframes anim-effect-sanja {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    }
    25% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }
  }
  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
  
  * {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  
  body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    color: #ADAFB6;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  #tooltip{
   position: absolute;
      width: 30px;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #000;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2px 0;
      font-size: x-small;
      border-radius: 6px;
      z-index: 1;
      transition: opacity .6s;
      transform: translate(26px ,3px);
      box-shadow: 0 4px 24px 0 rgb(161 161 161 / 97%);
  }
  
  
  #tooltip::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 24px 0 rgb(161 161 161 / 97%);
      right: 100%;
      margin-top: -5px;
      border-width: 5px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: transparent #cdcdcd transparent transparent;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="ui-slider-handle puls">
    <span id="tooltip"> </span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 35 35" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
        <circle cx="17.5" cy="15.5" r="11.5" />
        <circle cx="17.5" cy="15.5" r="11.5" />
      </g>
      <defs>
        <filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="35" height="35" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
          <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" />
          <feOffset dy="2" />
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
          <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.0666667 0 0 0 0 0.0666667 0 0 0 0 0.0666667 0 0 0 0.22 0" />
          <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow" />
          <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape" />
        </filter>
      </defs>

    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```